# magento 1.7.2 no emails sent

Tags: email, magento, smtp

I have been using magento for a very long time, I have never had an issue with not being able to send emails. Although I am now running a store on magento 1.7.2 and I am experiencing issues with new orders not sending emails. All of my settings are set exactly like magento 1.7

Comment: Could be manythings causing this... Is magento 1.7 still installed on the same system, and still able to successfully send emails?

Comment: magento 1.7 are running on other dedicated servers and they email just fine. This is a new server with magento 1.7.2 installed all options and config have been set the same as all other previous installations still no emails? Also I can send a test e-mail directly from my email to this e-mail, so the e-mail does function just not through magento like it should for new orders etc.. Thanks!

Comment: Have you double-checked that the "Disable Email Communications" setting is "No" in System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings

Comment: If you are running linux.. log in and check you mail queue ... see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-sendmail-mail-queue/

Comment: Try to disable cache and flush all other four cache mentioned in admin panel page.